# Independent UI element on a web page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing  Chrome extension that shows context menu after text selection. To achive that I inject iframe tag, with my menu, into a web page. This method works, but it modifies a web page so in some cases web page may not work properly. My question: Is there any "Chrome specific" way to display independent, from web page, UI(like Browser Action popup window)?

Comment: How about https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus ? Has a "selection" option.

Comment: @NitzanShaked This is not what I'm looking for. Anyway, as far as I know my task is unattainable with current Chrome API.